# Usage of 'EACH'

Tags: prepositions

Which  auxiliary (**is** or **are**) is to be used in the sentence:

> A copy each of the invitation and Special Report is/are forwarded herewith.

Answer (score -1):

'They are a poor family of five persons; all they have is each other.'
The determiner 'each' looks at individuals separately. So it is not correct to say, 'all they have *are* each other'.

Thus 'a copy each of invitation and Report' is viewed as two separate matters.

That they are forwarded together, in the same envelope, as a plurality, is irrelevant. 'Each' views the individual items as separate entities.

Thus a copy [of] each is forwarded.

Comment: The argument in your first paragraph doesn't hold. The "is" in "all they have *is ..." agrees numerically with "all they have", not with "each other".

Comment: @ Lawrence What if I say, 'Each other is all they have' ?

Comment: In that case, *is* would agree numerically with *each other*. This could form the basis of a valid argument.